# MySQL: Why default NULL instead of empty?

Tags: mysql

Why would you default a field to NULL instead of just leaving the value empty?  Is it merely so you can query `IS NULL` ?

I'm specifically asking about `INT` or other numerical data types

Comment: Because there no EMPTY in INT - it is NULL instead

Answer (score 8):

Because there's a semantic difference between `NULL` and empty.

If a field is empty, how can you tell the difference between the following?

1. the value is known to be empty
2. the value is unknown

That's what `NULL` is for: if you don't know the value then use `NULL`; if you know the value -- empty or not -- then use it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such notion as "empty" in MySQL.

For example, an int column is either an integer, or NULL.

If you don't specify a default value for your int column, if you try to insert a new row without specifying something for this column, mysql will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

Define "leaving the value empty". An empty value **is** null. If you mean empty = 0, then think about an account (money wise). You can have an account with 0$ in it, but you also can have no account at all (null). There is a difference between 0 and null.